# Highlighting duplicate values and drawing down from a list in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have two lists, a lists of orders and a list of inventories. I would like to draw down from my inventory and consume (highlight, or paste Order into new column) the orders that I can fill top to bottom so that I can see what rows I can/cannot fulfill. So based on the example below

```
Customer  |  Product | Qty           Product  | Qty
--------------------------           --------------
John      |  Apples  |  2            Apples   |  3
George    | Bananas  |  1            Bananas  |  2
Mike      |  Apples  |  1            Oranges  |  1
Matt      | Oranges  |  1
Allen     |  Apples  |  2
Robert    | Bananas  |  2
Paul      | Bananas  |  1
Kyle      | Oranges  |  1
```

John and Mike, would get highlighted (or the others with apples wouldn't, whatever way is easier), while Allen wouldn't, as I don't have enough apples for him. George would get Banana's since he is first, but Robert wouldn't since I don't have enough for him, but I do have enough for Paul, so Paul will get banana's. Matt get's Oranges since he is first one the list. If I have to user helper columns then sure, not a problem. But I can't figure out how to draw down, This is an easy solution with SQL, but I'd like to avoid that and find a formula, any ideas?

Comment: What have you tried? :)

Comment: I've tried a variation of sumif but each time I get highlights of everything. it won't draw down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom formatting with a formula and use this:
`=IF(SUMIF($B$2:$B2,$B2,$C$2:$C2)<=INDEX($I$2:$I$4,MATCH($B2,$H$2:$H$4,0)),TRUE,FALSE)`

Make sure the cell references match when making the formatting rule by making sure that the top-left-most cell is active...

[image]